# Центр обновления Windows сильная нагрузка на ЦП

Tags: windows, windows-7, update, windows-8

С чем может быть связана? Компы рабочие, в основном на pentium g2xxx-3xxx 4gb. Раньше включенная служба центра обновлений доставляла беды пользователям за компами на семерках (жрет все ресурсы под ноль, невозможно даже блокнотик открыть без лагов), сейчас проблема проявилась и на некоторых компах под управлением Win8.1. Пришлось временно отключить обновления, но ведь это не выход? С чем связана такая жесткая нагрузка Windows Update? Неужели какая-то хитрая политика Microsoft по вытеснению старых ОС >_<

Comment: Может запускается `ngen` из-за свежеприлетевшего нет-фреймворка?

Comment: Я полагаю, для этого был бы отдельный процесс, а так систему нагружает хост служб со службой центра, и если службу центра отключить, нагрузка сразу пропадает.

Comment: Ок. А в журналах есть какая-нить инфа о том, что какое-то обновление установилось плохо или не установилось? Если его руками скачать и прокликать?

Comment: Вроде как нет, еще уточню этот момент завтра. Но вообще у Microsoft как я знаю не выходят обновления ежедневно, а компы висят каждый день в течении всего рабочего дня.

Comment: Можно ещё эти кб забанить: https://www.getblackbird.net/blacklist/updates.txt